# TC3: Calling an FB method from the XAE Environment for testing purposes

Tags: twincat

I was wondering if it is possible to call a method directly from the XAE environment (online) for testing purposes. This would vastly reduce the amount of time to quickly test a function.

As an example; now I would write for each method:

```
IF bTestMethod THEN
   fbFunctionBlock.method(parameters);
   bTestMethod := FALSE;
END_IF
```

It would be nice to be able to call the function directly from the header within the online XAE interface by (for example) using a pragma like properties.

Maybe this functionality is already available that I'm not aware of? What would be the best / fastest way to test methods?

Thanks in advance,

Wouter

Answer (score 2):

> It would be nice to be able to call the function directly from the header within the online XAE interface by (for example) using a pragma like properties.

There is a pragma for calling methods remotely [{attribute 'TcRpcEnable'}](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/7145472907.html). But I don't know of any way to call it directly from XAE.

In the past I have used this pragma to test a method against an online 'calculator' with the help of node-red and [this](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-ads-client) ADS node.
You can also add the method with the pragma to an opc-ua server. And use a client like [UA-Expert](https://www.unified-automation.com/products/development-tools/uaexpert.html) to call the method manually.

Once you added the pragma, there are multiple ways to call it and test it over Ads. For many languages is a library available to make the ads calls. You can build a small test script, or a full test framework.

Like already mentioned in other answers, there is also a unit-testing library available to test code inside the controller without the need for extra software and pragma's: [TcUnit](https://tcunit.org/)

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe this functionality is already available that I'm not aware of?

Not that I'm aware of. There is no way to just call a function/method from XAE, because all the code is executed cyclically. So you need some way to 'activate' the function.

> What would be the best / fastest way to test methods?

Make [unit tests](https://alltwincat.com/2021/02/16/unit-testing-in-the-world-of-industrial-automation/) for individual functions and function blocks. Or you can make a [digital twin to simulate machine behavior](https://cookncode.com/twincat/2021/08/17/tc-simulation.html).